# Error con el motor del plantilla handlebars

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, handlebars

Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "perfil" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details

//Quiero acceder al nombre de usuario y me aparece el error que esta arriba.

```
{{#if usuario}}
       {{usuario.Seguir.perfil}}
{{/if}}
```

//solo me deja visualizar el objeto pero no me deja acceder a los valores

```
{{#if usuario}}
       {{usuario.Seguir}}
{{/if}}
```

//Asi solo me muestra el objeto con los datos dentro

//No puedo acceder a una propiedad de un objeto debido a este error, a alguien le paso o alguien sabe como solucionarlo??

Answer (score -1):

Para solucionar el error, solo basta con agregar .lean() para obtener un objeto JSON

```
dbName.find().lean()
```

La solucion la estraje desde acá:
[Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property “from” because it is not an “own property” of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690923/handlebars-access-has-been-denied-to-resolve-the-property-from-because-it-is)